# StringUtils replace text in between two patterns

Tags: java, regex, apache-utils

Hi I found really useful the apache operator

```
StringUtils.substringBetween(fileContent, "<![CDATA[", "]]>")
```

to extract information inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<envelope>
    <xxxx>
        <yyyy>
            <![CDATA[

                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
                    <Document >
                        <eee>
                            <tt>
                                <ss>zzzzzzz</ss>
                                <aa>2021-09-09T10:39:29.850Z</aa>
                                <aaaa>
                                    <Cd>cccc</Cd>
                                </aaaa>
                                <dd>ssss</dd>
                                <ff></ff>
                            </tt>
                        </eee>
                    </Document>
                ]]>
        </yyyy>
    </xxxx>
</envelope>
```

But now what I'm looking is another operator or regex that allow me to replace a dynamic xml

```
![CDATA["old_xml"]]
```

by another xml

```
![CDATA["new_xml"]]
```

Any idea idea how to accomplish this?

Regards.

Comment: This works great..... until you have an XML with two CDATA sections, one after the other.  As has been discussed at [***great and passionate length***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/18157) on this site over the past decade, regex is categorically the WRONG tool for working with arbitrary XML, HTML, JSON, etc.  You need a real parser for whatever flavor you're dealing with.  _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems." -- [Jamie Zawinski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski)_

Comment: 100% agree, but I only extracting the "text" from CDATA, once that I extract the text I use DOM parser

Comment: If you insist on using regex, be prepared for it to break when you least expect it.  Also prepare to be cursed by whoever has to maintain it.

Comment: The idea has been finally rejected XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `StringUtils`, you can use `String#replaceAll` method:

```sh
fileContent = fileContent
  .replaceAll("(?s)(<!\\[CDATA\\[).+?(]]>)", "$1foo$2");
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?s)`: Enable `DOTALL` mode so that `.` can match line breaks as well in `.+?`
- `(<!\\[CDATA\\[)`: Match opening `<![CDATA[` substring and capture in group #1
- `.+?`: Match 0 or more of any characters including line break
- `(]]>)`: Match closing `]]?` substring and capture in group #2
- `$1foo$2`: Replace with `foo` surrounded with back-references of capture group 1 and 2 on both sides

Comment: @paul: Answer is updated. Had you provided this use-case data upfront we would have got to this answer in first go itself.

Comment: `.replaceAll("(?s)(<!\\[CDATA\\[).+?(]]>)", "$1foo$2")` -- what is `(?s)`?  Did you mean `(?:\\s)`?

Comment: @JimGarrison: `(?s)` is for enabling `DOTALL` mode so that `.` can match line breaks as well in `.+?`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/NaMFEh/1), `(\<!\[CDATA\[).*?(\]\]>)`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = """
                ...
                    <data><![CDATA[a < b]]></data>
                ...
                """;

        String replacement = "foo";

        xml = xml.replaceAll("(\\<!\\[CDATA\\[).*?(\\]\\]>)", "$1" + replacement + "$2");

        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
...
    <data><![CDATA[foo]]></data>
...
```

**Explanation of the regex**:

- `(` : Start of group#1

  - `\<!\[CDATA\[` : String `<![CDATA[`
- `)` : End of group#1
- `.*?` : Any character any number of times
- `(` : Start of group#2

  - `\]\]>`: String `]]>`
- `)` : End of group#2